# Opening keyboard destroys the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with my layouting. In my layout I have an EditText, a DatePicker, a TimePicker and a Button. Clicking on the EditText opens the keyboard which causes the problem shown in the picture. Different methods from "android:windowSoftInputMode" did not change anything. Right now I do not have a clue how to tackle this problem.

Is it a good idea to hide the other components until a text is entered? What is the expected behaviour here?

[image: correct layout]

[image: crumbled layout]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="patrickengelkes.com.alleneune.activities.CreateEventActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/event_name_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/event_date_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/event_name_edit_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send_event_invites"
    android:text="@string/send_event_invites_to_members"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/event_time_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/send_event_invites"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/event_time_picker"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/event_time_picker" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a picture of your layout without the keyboard open? Or rather a picture of what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: `Different methods from "android:windowSoftInputMode"` what exactly did you try? And what is the `theme` of your `activity`?

Comment: I tried "adjustPan", "stateHidden", "stateAlwaysHidden" and "adjust resize". None seemed to change anything. Added a picture for the correct layout in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is the problem:

You are telling your `DatePicker` that it should be below the `EditText` which is fixed at the top!

Then you are telling your `TimerPicker` to be above your `Button` which is fixed at the bottom.

Now when you open the `SoftInput` the Button moves up, so does your `TimePicker`. But the EditText stays fixed at top, so does your `DatePicker`.

Both `TimePicker` and `DatePicker` got `wrap_content` so the only way `TimePicker` can go is into `DatePicker`! And that's exactly what it looks like!

I would try to tell `TimePicker` that i should stay below `DatePicker`:

```
android:below=="@id/event_date_picker"
```

and see what happens! Because in that case it is forced to stay below `DatePicker` and not acting like a layer anymore floating into `DatePicker`! I didn't try it and maybe you need to declare `android:windowSoftInputMode` correctly. Because i'm not sure how it is declared right now! 
Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes this worked. Unfortunately the date picker is still a little bit under the EditText. As you can see in the first picture the January isn't completely visible.

Comment: @deutro glad to help you. The first one  looks good to me i think you mean the second one

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant the second picture.

Comment: @Deutro that also happens at a `google app` which i saw yesterday at a collegues phone. You also have the option, as you said, to `setVisibily=invisble` when `SoftInput` is open to completely be sure nothing is overlapping or is being overlapped.

Comment: What is the best method to do this? Set a focus listener to the EditText and set the items to visible? How can someone click on the next item if its not visible? Right now I do not have the best solution for the user experience I guess.

Comment: @deutro please do some research or ask a new question if you can't find a solution. There are many ways do detect if softinput is open.